# Ingress losing some settings on restart (k3s)

Tags: kubernetes, k3s, traefik, cert-manager

I'm experimenting with some Kubernetes stuff TrueNAS Scale, which comes with k3s (1.25.3) installed. I installed one of the TrueCharts apps (https://truecharts.org/) but the settings for it appear buggy. I had configured it to use a clusterissuer, but the relevant settings didn't end up in the (traefik) Ingress.

Therefore I manually changed the Ingress with `k3s kubectl edit` and managed to get my certificate issued with cert-manager.io. This is what the Ingress looks like after editing:

```
# I primarily added/changed:
# cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer annotation
# ingressClassName: traefik
# secretName under tls near the bottom
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: lets-encrypt-xxxxxx
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: dokuwiki
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: ix-dokuwiki
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.entrypoints: websecure
  creationTimestamp: "2023-03-29T14:08:05Z"
  generation: 13
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: dokuwiki
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: dokuwiki
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "20220731.1"
    helm-revision: "6"
    helm.sh/chart: dokuwiki-5.0.25
  name: dokuwiki
  namespace: ix-dokuwiki
  resourceVersion: "6123797"
  uid: fab6a1dd-6edd-4f8f-9e83-d4f1ed72dd1c
spec:
  ingressClassName: traefik
  rules:
  - host: myhost.mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: dokuwiki
            port:
              name: main
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - myhost.mydomain.com
    secretName: myhost-mydomain-com-tls
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 192.168.0.11
```

It seemed to work well enough, but **when I stop and restart the app** in the TrueNAS UI, the **secretName disappears** for some reason, even though the added annotation is kept, for example. This leads to the certificate not being used, but worse, it is also deleted so a new certificate will have to be issued when I add the secretName back. That's pretty bad, and obviously I want to keep my settings between restarts.

What causes this behavior and how can I prevent it?